# Howto properly mount /proc, /run to prevent chroot from being able to see or kill processes belonging to the host

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I use a loop in a script to `mount --bind` special filesystems such as `/dev`, `/dev/pts`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys` (and `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` optionally) this way :

```bash
for specialFS in dev dev/pts proc run sys
do
    test -d $destinationRootDir/$specialFS/ || sudo mkdir $destinationRootDir/$specialFS/
    sudo mount -v --bind /$specialFS $destinationRootDir/$specialFS
done
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && sudo mkdir -p $destinationRootDir/sys/firmware/efi/efivars && sudo mount -v --bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars $destinationRootDir/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

Then I go into the chroot :

```bash
sudo chroot $destinationRootDir

mount -a
update-grub
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && grub-install --efi-directory=$(mount | awk '/\/efi /{print$3}') || grub-install $destinationDisk
umount -a
umount /usr && exit
```

The problem is that `/usr` cannot be unmounted because the chroot environment thinks `/usr` is being used by processes that I was able to find running on the host.

So I guess I should NOT use `mount --bind` for `/proc` and/or for `/run`.

Ho can I mount these two properly for my chroot environment to be isolated on the process level ?

Answer (score 0):

chroot wasn't designed as security boundary so you shouldn't use it if you don't trust the code inside jail. Check https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1975883
Additionaly if you expose dev/pts it's big chance that your command is launched outside jail via pseudoterminal. It's hard to guess without exact command and parent pid of that command.

Comment: I don't use `chroot` for security purposes. I use `chroot` to repair another Linux system. Still, how can I mount `/run` for the `chroot` environment ?

Comment: You need to answer first why would you like to mount /run, what parts of it to access and under what privileges - you are saying that something is modified while you don't intended to do so - then it's about security. But to configure it properly you need to identify what you or your tool want exactly want achieve under the hood so those mount points are needed

Comment: `update-grub` (or `grub-install`, I cant remember which one) needs `/run`